# Difference between non-executable directory with and without write

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems

Is there a difference between a directory that is not writable (and not executable) and one that *is* writable (but still not executable)? It seems to me that they are equivalent, because creating/deleting files requires both write and execute, but I have not been able to find a definite source to answer this.

TLDR: What's the difference (if any) between these two directories:

```
dr--------. 1 bob bob 0 Mar  8 23:49 dir1
drw-------. 1 bob bob 0 Mar  8 23:49 dir2
```

Comment: Hard to prove to a 100 % without looking at the code or exhaustively trying all possible operations, but I'm pretty sure you're right, the only difference is that `rw-` is more confusing. The only way to write to a directory is to create/rename/remove a file within it, and that requires accessing "past" the final slash in the path, which requires the `x` permission. Reading is different since you can just open the directory itself for reading. That's not possible for writing, and trying to do that gives the EISDIR error.